# Mac - A Twitter client without growl

Tags: macos, mac, twitter, growl, tweetdeck

What's is the best OS X Twitter client that doesn't use Growl? I'm looking for something like the old Adobe Air Tweetdeck, with tweet notifications in a window with clickable links and options to reply tweet in notification window.

Comment: Can't you just disable Growl?

Comment: If I disable Growl, I won't get notifications, slhck. I want notifications, but not in Growl way.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to System Preferences -> Growl and select the Applications tab across the top, you should be able to turn off Growl notifications for whichever Twitter app that you choose to use.

You will still receive Growl notifications for all of your other apps.